Separa un registro por año segun su rango de fechas
Tengo los siguentes datos



Empleado
FechaInicio
FechaFin
Dias




10361
2019-07-22
2019-07-26
5


10361
2019-12-23
2020-01-03
12


10361
2020-04-06
2020-04-08
3



En el cual lo que busco obtener es poder separar el segundo registro en 2 para tener solo los dias del año 2019 y los de año 2020
Asi:



Empleado
FechaInicio
FechaFin
Dias




10361
2019-07-22
2019-07-26
5


10361
2019-12-23
2019-12-31
9


10361
2020-01-01
2020-01-03
3


10361
2020-04-06
2020-04-08
3



Saludos

ok.. y esto lo queres hacer con sql, o como?? porque en un procedimiento es una pavada... ademas.. ojo... porque sql no inventa datos donde no hay,,,

En el cual lo que busco obtener es poder separar el segundo registro en 2 para tener solo los dias del año 2019 y los de año 2020. Ese argumento no se entiende. ¿Qué quieres decir con eso exactamente? ¿Cuál es la consulta que genera esos datos? ¿Qué consulta has intentado? ¿En qué SGBD está la tabla en cuestión? Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

El segundo Registro el cual su "FechaInicio" es 2019-12-23 y su "FechaFin" es  2020-01-03, de una fecha a la otra son 12 dias en total, la cual el rango abarca del año 2019 al 2020, necesito poder separala, ya sea creando un registro aparte o solo dejando los dias pero necesito poder tener los 9 dias del año 2019 y los 3 dias del año 2020 por separado

La respuesta a esta pregunta depende del motor de datos que uses. Coloca la etiqueta correspondiente al motor para que pueda ser respondida.

@gbianchi, dado que la pregunta tiene la etiqueta SQL, diría que SI, lo quiere hacer con SQL. Y no hace falta inventar ningún dato, el AP los ha dejado en las tablas de la pregunta, que es bastante clara.

@jachguate un SP tambien seria sql... me referia a que OP no especifico ni motor (muy importante, tu respuesta requiere muchos retoques para que ande por ejemplo en oracle) ni si era necesario un query o algun otra variable..

@gbianchi, Claro, la parte del motor es vital, como ya dije en un comentario anterior. No hay manera de hacerlo con el puro estándar. Pero si el AP toma la idea, considero que no sería tan complicado adaptarlo de un motor a otro. En unos 5 minutos escribí esta solución para Oracle

Te propongo esta solución:
SELECT *,
  IF(YEAR(FechaInicio)=YEAR(FechaFin),
    DATEDIFF(FechaFin,FechaInicio)+1,
    DATEDIFF(CONCAT(YEAR(FechaInicio),'-12-31'),FechaInicio)+1
  ) dias,
  IF(YEAR(FechaInicio)=YEAR(FechaFin),
    0,
    DATEDIFF(FechaFin,CONCAT(YEAR(FechaFin),'-01-01'))+1
  ) dias_sig_ano
  FROM fechas;

Obtenida para este dataset:
CREATE TABLE fechas(
  Empleado int,
  FechaInicio date,
  FechaFin date
  );
INSERT INTO fechas (Empleado, FechaInicio, FechaFin) VALUES
('10361','2019-07-22','2019-07-26'),
('10361','2019-12-23','2020-01-03'),
('10361','2020-04-06','2020-04-08');

Con la que obtendrás:
+----------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
| Empleado | FechaInicio | FechaFin   | dias | dias_sig_ano |
+----------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
|    10361 | 2019-07-22  | 2019-07-26 |    5 |            0 |
|    10361 | 2019-12-23  | 2020-01-03 |    9 |            3 |
|    10361 | 2020-04-06  | 2020-04-08 |    3 |            0 |
+----------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+

Espero que te resulte útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Yo lo resolvería, primero calculando los nuevos períodos que solo estén dentro del mismo año, lo que conseguiría haciendo la unión de:

Todos los registros de la tabla, con su fecha inicial y teniendo el cuidado de, para los registros que abarcan dos años, dejar como fecha fin el 31 de diciembre.
Todos los registros que abarcan dos años, colocando como fecha inicial el 1 de enero y dejando la fecha final del registro.

Con estos datos en un CTE, finalmente calcular los días que corresponden a cada período, valiéndome de la función datediff().
Asumiendo que la tabla subyacente se llame Datos, para SQL Server la solución luciría algo como:
with
DatosPorAnio as (
select   Empleado
       , FechaInicio
       , case YEAR(FechaInicio) 
           when YEAR(FechaFin) then FechaFin
           else CAST(cast(Year(FechaInicio) as varchar(4)) + '1231' as date)
         end FechaFin
  from Datos
union all
select   Empleado
       , CAST(cast(Year(FechaFin) as varchar(4)) + '0101' as date) FechaInicio
       , FechaFin
  from Datos
 where YEAR(FechaInicio) != YEAR(FechaFin)
)
select *
       , DATEDIFF(day, FechaInicio, FechaFin) + 1 Dias
  from DatosPorAnio
 order by FechaInicio

Fiddle
El resultado es:
Empleado    FechaInicio FechaFin   Dias
----------- ----------- ---------- -----------
10361       2019-07-22  2019-07-26 5
10361       2019-12-23  2019-12-31 9
10361       2020-01-01  2020-01-03 3
10361       2020-04-06  2020-04-08 3

Con esta misma idea, se puede escribir la consulta para cualquier motor que soporte una versión moderna de SQL.
